# How do I delete a symlink from /sbin?

Tags: boot, mount, delete, busybox

I wanted to remove a symlink from `/sbin/` directory. The link is `swapon` which is linked to `busybox` binary on the same directory.

While trying to remove first-time, it said "Read only filesystem". So, I remounted `/` with read-write using this command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then I was able to remove it. I checked with `which swapon` as well as using `ls`. All fine. Now, when I rebooted the phone, the link appeared in the same location magically!

Am I missing something? What's happening here? How do I remove this link?

Here is the output of `mount` in case it is required

```
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=750,gid=1000)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory)
tmpfs on /mnt/asec type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /mnt/obb type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6 on /modemfs type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 on /system type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p11 on /data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,journal_async_commit,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 on /cache type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered)
/dev/block/vold/179:97 on /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/fuse on /storage/sdcard1 type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/block/vold/179:14 on /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0 type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/vold/179:14 on /mnt/secure/asec type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/fuse on /storage/sdcard0 type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/block/dm-0 on /mnt/asec/com.zodinplex.naturesound-1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1)
```

Comment: you can give Root Explorer/Total Commander a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android devices have a unique way of booting, using a binary blob called `boot.img` that contains the kernel, and a ramdisk. This ramdisk will contain the `/sbin` symlink you want to remove.

To remove this, you will probably need either an upgrade image, or you will have to extract `boot.img` from your device. I can look for or put together instructions for this if you wish.

Once you have the extracted `boot.img`, you have to then extract the ramdisk image from it, make your changes, and put everything back together.

**Then comes the dangerous part, unless you know you cannot brick your phone. You will need to flash this (hopefully working!) `boot.img` so that Android will use the new ramdisk.**

So, for now, it might be better to figure out if there is an init script in the `/system` directory that you could remove your symlink in each time your phone starts.

> **Update:** or, like you did, you could just change the init script that calls `swapon` to call a different one.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this. I wasn't aware of this. I might try changing these, but I solved the problem by explicitly calling another symlink `/system/bin/swapon` without relying on env's default `swapon` (which was in `/sbin`). I think, I'll try it later and inform you